# Android webView shouldInterceptRequest - Stop Loading Resource

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to intercept and stop loading all mp4 videos on a `webView`, for that I'm using `shouldInterceptRequest`. I'm able to intercept the videos and, for ex:, show a dialog but, but I'm not able to stop loading them, any idea why?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
        try { 
            if (url.contains(".mp4?")) {
                return getResponseData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    private WebResourceResponse getResponseData() {
        try {
            String str = "Access Denied";
            InputStream data = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain that your `getResponseData` method is not returning null? That would cause the video the continue loading. Have you tried debugging the app using your IDE to see what exactly it's doing?

Comment: Put a log after `if(url.contain(".mp4?))` . And why you have `?` after `.mp4` ? If the log wont show use `if(url.endsWith(".mp4")` .

Answer (score 4):

This may help you:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    if (yourCondition) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YourwebView.stopLoading();
                YourwebView.doAnythingYouWant();
            }
        });
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

I created the thread because `A WebView method ( that is stopLoading() ) can't be called on a currently running thread and that thread is 'Chrome_FileThread'`.

Also, get `getMainLooper()` because `In above situation we can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML page does not show mp4 contents or handles invalid content, then you can simply pass some dummy InputStream to WebResourceResponse as shown below.

```
my_webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
        if (request?.url?.contains(".mp4") == true) {
            val inputStream = "".byteInputStream(Charset.defaultCharset())
            return WebResourceResponse("image/png", "UTF-8", inputStream)
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is this one I think

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               // code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: any luck with the above?

Comment: Actually, the method I needed was really `shouldInterceptRequest`, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (yourCondition) {
                    webView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            webView.stopLoading();
                        }
                    });
                }

                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).